# Please verify correctness of $H_2(e^{j\theta}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h_2[n] \cdot e^{-j\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, signal-processing

This frequency spectrum of a signal $h_2[n]$ is bugging me. I am not sure if what I've done here is correct. It's the sum

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

in particular I'm struggling with. Afaik this sum is equal to zero but in that case anything of that signal would be zero. Since there are a few other examples which require me to have a correct $H_2(e^{j\theta})$ I'm asking if someone could verify the correctness of this:

\begin{align*}
H_2(e^{j\theta}) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h_2[n] \cdot e^{-jn\theta} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (0.15 \cdot \delta[n] + 0.3 \cdot \delta[n-1] + 0.15 \cdot \delta[n-2]) (-1)^{n-1}  \cdot e^{-jn\theta} \\
&= (0.15 + 0.3 \cdot e^{-j\theta} + 0.15 \cdot e^{-j2\theta}) \cdot  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \\
&= 0.3 \cdot (\frac{1}{2} + \cdot e^{-j\theta} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{-j2\theta}) \cdot  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \\
&= 0.3 e^{-j\theta} \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{2} ( e^{j\theta} + e^{-j\theta})) \cdot  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \\
&= 0.3 e^{-j\theta} \cdot (1 + cos(\theta)) \cdot  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \\
\end{align*}

If that is correct, then this should be correct too:

\begin{align*}
|H_2(e^{j\theta})| &= \Big|0.3 e^{-j\theta} \cdot (1 + cos(\theta)) \cdot  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\Big| \\
&= 0.3 \cdot |(1 + cos(\theta))| \cdot \Big|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\Big| \\
\end{align*}

But since

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} = 0
\end{align*}

what would be the point of this anyway?

I assume that I made a mistake or a false assumption somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that the sum converges as it approaches $\infty$? It looks like it will just oscillate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Only three elements of the sum are non-zero. So you get a finite sum over just three elements. And by the way, the first sum you're referring does not converge.

Comment: :D Thanks! I just didn't see that. And you're right, that sum does not converge of course!